# jQuery select cell horizontally or vertically only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grid

**Description**

I have created a grid of 12x12. And each cell has id as '_1', '_2', etc.
For example.

```
<span id="_1">L</span>
<span id="_2">B</span>
```

I am using the following code to highlight when dragged.

```
function initWordSearch() {
    var active = false;

    $("#game-section span").mousedown(function(ev) {
        active = true;
        $(".highlightE").removeClass("highlightE"); // clear previous selection
        ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
        $(this).addClass("highlightE");
    });

    $("#game-section span").mousemove(function(ev) {
        if (active) {
        console.log($(this).text());
        $(this).addClass("highlightE");
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(ev) {
        active = false;
    });

}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    initWordSearch();
});
```

**To Achieve**

Currently, where ever I move my mouse that box gets selected.
**I want to select boxes either in horizontally from left to right or vertically from top to bottom only.**

Here's the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/tsuppdot) for current progress.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider setting some global variables to hold positions of the targeted spans and then comparing them:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsuppdot/5/)

See JS comments for more explainations

```
  // Set global variables for comparisons
  var active, start, startX, startY, axis;

  $("#game-section span").mousedown(function(ev) {
    start = $(this)
    active = true;
    $(".highlightE").removeClass("highlightE"); // clear previous selection
    ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
    start.addClass("highlightE");

    // Set global variables
    var position = start.position()
    startX = position.left;
    startY = position.top;
  });

  $("#game-section span").mousemove(function(ev) {
    // Get direction of the first highlighted span to compare
    if(!$(this).hasClass('highlightE') && active) {
      var position = $(this).position();
      var x = position.left;
      var y = position.top;

      // Only decide which way the highlights should go on the first one highlighted
      if(!axis) {
        x === startX ? axis = 'y' : axis = 'x';
      }

      // If axis is equal to y, it should go sideways
      if(axis === 'y' && x === startX && y > startY) {
        $(this).addClass("highlightE");
      }

      // If its x, it should go up and down
      if(axis === 'x' && y === startY && x > startX) {
        $(this).addClass("highlightE");
      }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, your code is working fine. but i am able to select from right to left also. It should select from top to bottom or from left to right.

Comment: Updated answer and fiddle. I missed that part, but the necessary variables were already present. Just need to add in one more comparison for each if statement. https://jsfiddle.net/tsuppdot/5/

Comment: Great!, and useful. But I need some implementation into this. That is the first and last cell should be rounded. can you please help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, firstly you need to know the `Columns` and `Rows` for each cell in the grid, and what direction is the operation currently works with (`Vertical` or `Horizontal`)

To get the `Columns` and `Rows` from your current markup, you can get it by using the `id` like this

```
var curID = parseInt($(this)[0].id.replace('_', ''));
var curRow = Math.floor(curID / 12);
var curCol = curID % 12;
```

- You don't need to decide whether if the results of `curRow` or `curCol` is 0 equal with row = 1 or col = 12 because all you need is to know whether on the `mousemove` event, is it in the same row or col

Then you need to set the direction and last cell row & col, you can do it like this in the global variable

```
var direction = '';
var lastRow = -1;
var lastCol = -1;
```

And set the value in every event of `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup` whether to re-initialize the value or set the value to the current one, then check if the direction is not set, set it by checking in the `mousemove` event, is it in the same col or row (same col = vertical movement, same row = horizontal movement), and set it to the direction like this

```
if(direction === '') {
  direction = lastRow == curRow ? 'H' : lastCol == curCol ? 'V' : '';
}
```

Then before giving the Highlight, add another validation, if the `direction = 'V'` that means you need to highlight only the cell with the `same cur col with the last col` and have the `cur row equals last row + 1`, and update the last value with the current one like this

```
if((direction == 'H' && curRow == lastRow && curCol == lastCol + 1) || (direction == 'V' && curRow == lastRow + 1 && curCol == lastCol)) {
  $(this).addClass("highlightE");
  lastRow = curRow;
  lastCol = curCol;
}
```

Here's the fully updated answer: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tsuppdot/2/)